# Hide table or text based on text in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, element

I have to hide a table that looks like this:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
    <td style="color: #929292; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
    &copy; 1999 - 2012 MyCO&trade; Marketing Technologies&trade;, MyApp<sup>&reg;</sup>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tried just about everything, nothing seems to work. When I tried the various contains, I get a null error and if I include the full text I get a string error.

Comment: So you are wanting to hide a table if it includes the EXACT text included in the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var cells = $("table td");
        var str = "&copy; 1999 - 2012 PTI&trade; Marketing Technologies&trade;, MarcomCentral<sup>&reg;</sup>";
        var encodedText = $("<div></div>").html(str).text();

        cells.each(function(i, element) {
            var jqElement = $(element);
            if (jqElement.text().indexOf(encodedText) != -1)
                jqElement.hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: still unterminated string constant. The exact string is:  &copy; 1999 - 2012 PTI&trade; Marketing Technologies&trade;, MarcomCentral<sup>&reg;</sup>

Comment: You've got to be copy and pasting it wrong. I've tested this with your exact HTML code, and it works 100%...no Javascript errors. I also modified it to contain the exact string you just provided.

Comment: I changed it one more time to handle html entities in case that is what is throwing it off.

Comment: I wish I could say it worked but all I get is "object does not support this property or method"

Comment: I'm out of ideas. There must be something you aren't telling us.

Comment: I do not know what more I could tell. There is a text section I can add text to that appears above the table I want to hide. It does allow <script></script> blocks as well as <style></style> blocks which I am using to hide a div that has a class name. This code get "spit" into the page above the table I am trying to hide.

Comment: Seems we need to verify that jQuery is even working first. Try: `$(document).ready(function() { alert('test'); });`

Comment: looks like it is not, I will try to place a reference to jquery then re-run.

Comment: ok, I got it to work (kind of) when I use your (crush) solution, the whole page disapeers, when I use alpaca it works but there is an error in the vendors javascript, conflict between the jquery ref I put in and their refs?

Comment: The whole page disappears? How is that possible... Can we see this page in question our solutions in tact?

Comment: http://members.printable.com/quad/training_maxwell_travel/

That is a link to the page I am working on. If you view source you will see the area I can change. It starts with <!-- UILayout start: layout_FooterCopy -->

and ends with 

<!-- UILayout end: layout_FooterCopy -->

Comment: Can we chat somewhere? I don't see the any of the code I've posted on that page anywhere.

Comment: I have a meeting and will be back in about an hour. I will put your code back in so you can see it in the meantime.

Comment: I see the issue. prototype.js is conflicting with jQuery. I edited my code to hopefully resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution based on the HTML you provided:

```
$(function() {
    var text = 'MyApp'; // set the text string
    $('table tr td:contains('+ text +')') // find the td that contains the text
    .parents('table') // select the parent table
    .first() // reduce results to first table
    .hide(); // hide it
});
```

Comment: The text is not exact, but close. MYCO and MYAPP are different.

Comment: Do you want to match the HTML or just the text?

Comment: if even MYAPP matched that would work. This is a pre-built app that has this copyright in the bottom, we are allowed to get rid of it but the vendor refuses to help. I have to place the javascript into a text field that appears above this table and save it. The text field is just like comments here, you type them in and they show up, it does save the javascript however.

Comment: Gotcha...Feel free to mark this solution as answered if it solved your problem. Or let me know if you need more help.

Comment: No problem. Do you know if the app is for sure loading jQuery?

Comment: page has this call in it...<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

Comment: Not sure if you wrapped the code in a document ready handler or not. At any rate, I edited the code with the shorthand version for this along with one other minor change to the text var.

Comment: I wrapped it in the shortcut for jQuery's document.ready handler. Just copy and paste the code as is. Should work! Or, try crush's solution. Good luck

Comment: @crush, I tried it but I get cells is null or not an object error.

Comment: @alpaca lips nao
tried your solution, no error but it does nothing. I am not sure why none of these work, seems to me they should.

Comment: still unterminated string constant. The exact string is: &copy; 1999 - 2012 PTI&trade; Marketing Technologies&trade;, MarcomCentral<sup>&reg;</sup>